# dplyr::arrange refuse to arrange dataframe by timestamp column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe (here is the sample):

```
df <- structure(list(user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), obs_id = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), scroll_id = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), timestamp = c(-1.74966971796047, 
-1.70403832189443, -1.70379906928687, -1.70361867040459, -1.70347088963619, 
-1.70319128699835), row_num = 1:6, scroll_length = c(6, 9, 14, 
12, 13, 26), x_mean = c(-1.74134749014902, -1.19087086808828, 
1.36178725012622, -1.32786301490502, 1.24184201608646, -1.31953110973881
), y_mean = c(-4.93507461932646, 0.0304680987883223, 0.140001980341645, 
0.61911843405746, 0.434230282460559, 0.438563278736709), dx_mean = c(-0.514034686928457, 
-0.709482080612108, 0.924636289935977, -0.702980646737082, 0.515080876392673, 
-0.359676884238743), dy_mean = c(0.972265996197407, -0.692113718739584, 
-0.162463490249733, -0.373682612876388, -0.0663766957581004, 
0.293619375985922)), .Names = c("user_id", "obs_id", "scroll_id", 
"timestamp", "row_num", "scroll_length", "x_mean", "y_mean", 
"dx_mean", "dy_mean"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to arrange by timestamp column but I get the following error:

```
data %>% arrange(timestamp)
data %>% arrange("timestamp")
```

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : Argument 1 is of unsupported type
>   matrix

Please advise how to make it work. I know that timestamp is a function and matrix but here it's a column and I "want" `dplyr` to "understand" that it's a column.

As @sotos asked:

```
sessionInfo():

R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_IL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_IL.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_IL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2      rebus_0.1-3         philentropy_0.2.0   reshape2_1.4.3      broom_0.5.0         dummies_1.5.6       hms_0.4.2          
 [8] anytime_0.3.1       data.table_1.11.8   bit64_0.9-7         bit_1.1-14          car_3.0-2           carData_3.0-2       caret_6.0-80       
[15] lattice_0.20-35     xgboost_0.71.2      doSNOW_1.0.16       snow_0.4-3          doMC_1.3.5          iterators_1.0.10    foreach_1.4.4      
[22] randomForest_4.6-14 htmlwidgets_1.3     plotly_4.8.0        jsonlite_1.5        pROC_1.13.0         knitr_1.20          lubridate_1.7.4    
[29] MASS_7.3-49         chron_2.3-53        forcats_0.3.0       stringr_1.3.1       dplyr_0.7.7         purrr_0.2.5         readr_1.1.1        
[36] tidyr_0.8.2         tibble_1.4.2        ggplot2_3.1.0       tidyverse_1.2.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-137          dimRed_0.1.0          httr_1.3.1            tools_3.4.4           backports_1.1.2       R6_2.3.0             
 [7] rpart_4.1-13          rebus.base_0.0-3      lazyeval_0.2.1        colorspace_1.3-2      nnet_7.3-12           withr_2.1.2          
[13] tidyselect_0.2.5      curl_3.1              compiler_3.4.4        cli_1.0.1             rvest_0.3.2           xml2_1.2.0           
[19] scales_1.0.0          sfsmisc_1.1-2         DEoptimR_1.0-8        robustbase_0.93-3     RApiDatetime_0.0.4    digest_0.6.18        
[25] rebus.unicode_0.0-2   foreign_0.8-70        rio_0.5.10            pkgconfig_2.0.2       htmltools_0.3.6       rlang_0.3.0.1        
[31] readxl_1.1.0          ddalpha_1.3.4         rstudioapi_0.8        bindr_0.1.1           zip_1.0.0             ModelMetrics_1.2.0   
[37] magrittr_1.5          Matrix_1.2-14         Rcpp_0.12.19          munsell_0.5.0         abind_1.4-5           stringi_1.2.4        
[43] yaml_2.2.0            plyr_1.8.4            recipes_0.1.3         grid_3.4.4            pls_2.7-0             crayon_1.3.4         
[49] rebus.datetimes_0.0-1 haven_1.1.2           splines_3.4.4         pillar_1.3.0          rebus.numbers_0.0-1   codetools_0.2-15     
[55] stats4_3.4.4          CVST_0.2-2            magic_1.5-9           glue_1.3.0            modelr_0.1.2          cellranger_1.1.0     
[61] gtable_0.2.0          kernlab_0.9-27        assertthat_0.2.0      DRR_0.0.3             openxlsx_4.1.0        gower_0.1.2          
[67] prodlim_2018.04.18    class_7.3-14          survival_2.42-3       viridisLite_0.3.0     geometry_0.3-6        timeDate_3043.102    
[73] RcppRoll_0.3.0        lava_1.6.3            ipred_0.9-7
```

Comment: Thats the unfortunate side effect of Tidiverse doing away with quotes and brackets. Tidyverse syntax does away with quotes, but when you need to distinguish you cannot do so easily. Having to convert to data.table is a much heavier operation than reasonable for disambiguation between a function and a data frame column. A simple solution is to rename the column, but that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all comments, I have found out a solution:

My `df` dataframe is scaled and centered - the function that produces df returns:

```
scale(df)
```

When I have printed `str(df)` I have seen attributes saying that it's centered and scaled.

When converting to `data.table` it solved the issue:

```
df %>% as.data.table() %>% dplyr::arrange(obs_id, user_id, scroll_id, timestamp)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nice to see the solution.. also observed uneven number of data points in each variable like dx_mean, dy_mean have only 212 points vs obs_id which is 356 rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% arrange(timestamp)

arrange() from dplyr arranges as below in ascending order
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  user_id obs_id scroll_id timestamp row_num scroll_length x_mean  y_mean dx_mean dy_mean
    <int>  <int>     <int>     <dbl>   <int>         <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       1      1         3     -1.75       1             6  -1.74 -4.94    -0.514  0.972 
2       1      2         1     -1.70       2             9  -1.19  0.0305  -0.709 -0.692 
3       1      2         2     -1.70       3            14   1.36  0.140    0.925 -0.162 
4       1      2         3     -1.70       4            12  -1.33  0.619   -0.703 -0.374 
5       1      2         4     -1.70       5            13   1.24  0.434    0.515 -0.0664
6       1      2         5     -1.70       6            26  -1.32  0.439   -0.360  0.294
```